# Why AMAZON.COM and amazon.com both works as a url althought we know that URL is case sensitive?

Tags: http, url, https, dns, developer-tools

These lines are from a book :

> The path of a URL is case sensitive, meaning
> http://food.com/Broccoli is a different resource than
> http://food.com/broccoli, because one uses an uppercase B and one uses a lowercase b

Comment: Hostnames are not case-sensitive. The rest of the URL (path, query string) is.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>      foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
>      \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
>       |           |            |            |        |
>    scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
> ```

The above is from [the URI spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3).

`Amazon.com` is the host name, part of the authority, *not* part of the case-sensitive path.